# Pi won't reload etc/network/interfaces: Won't switch back to DHCP after static IP removed and networking restarted

Tags: networking, wifi, dhcp

I'm following [these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) to create an Ad-Hoc WiFi network from a Pi Zero W. It works great. Problem is, once I'm done I want to switch the Pi back to DHCP and log on to my house WiFi like normal.

1) Replace the old files: `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` to their original states from a backup before the Ad-Hoc instructions were followed

2) I'm trying to restart networking with:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

... and I've tried all these commands as well following that:

```
sudo service networking restart
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

No matter what I try, I can't get the Pi to give up it's static IP and connect normally back to my home WiFi... ***UNTIL*** I restart the computer. How else can I force the network to reload `/etc/network/interfaces` without powering cycling?

## EDIT:

Here's the interfaces file BEFORE adhoc, which is restored AFTER adhoc:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto wlan0

auto lo usb0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet manual
```

during adhoc the wlan0 part is changed to:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
```

...and that's the problem, I can't "clear" that static IP address so the Pi won't connect to my router.

Comment: How far did you get in the instructions, you have dnsmasq, dhcpcd, hostapd, and bridge network interface running in addition to the changes to network/interfaces. Some may be conflicting with normal use, hostapd will put your wlan0 into master mode and will be unable to bind to a wifi network.

Comment: sorry yeah I also `sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq` and `sudo systemctl stop hostapd`

Comment: Do you have "auto wlan0" statement in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: getting closer! Adding `auto wlan0` got the WiFi to connect (visible in `iwconfig`) but `ifconfig` still displays the static IP address, it won't work with my router with that static IP address. I'll try adding `dhcp` to `/etc/network/interfaces' next

Comment: nope, `DHCPDISCOVER` can't get an IP address

Comment: interfaces file added to OP -- no GUI, this is all terminal, yes wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: DHCPCD is still responsible for getting the DHCP address even as client, did you add `denyinterfaces wlan0` to `dhcpcd.conf` , did you restart dhcpcd service to release any leases you had from serving as AP?

Comment: BTW, for future reference, the easiest way to do this is to take advantage of `interfaces.d` you can symlink/unlink the correct configuration just for wlan0 into there.

Comment: yes `denyinterfaces` in dhcpcd.conf, which gets removed when I try to switch back to home wifi. also running `sudo service dhcpcd restart` after that switch is made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo service networking restart` will **DO NOTHING** on a normal Raspbian, because **it is not using networking** it is using `dhcpcd`.

Try this:

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload  
sudo systemctl start dhcpcd.service
# or if dhcpcd is already running:
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd.service
```

It is not clear what other services you may have started, so you should investigate and stop these.

Comment: I think this might be it! Thank you. Funny thing, `ifconfig` still shows the static IP address but `ip addr show` shows BOTH the old static IP and new one that must have come from my router via dhcp. Trying to figure that out next...